# Oracle synonym error from Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am getting below error in my application.

org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter -- ERROR -- ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid

i have checked the synonym,that is valid.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code where the exception is being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

You may have the synonym in VALID status which refers to even non-existing object:

```
SQL> create synonym t_syn for abrakadabra;

Synonym created.

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'T_SYN';

STATUS                                                                          
-------                                                                         
VALID                                                                           

SQL> select * from t_syn;
select * from t_syn
              *
error in line 1:
ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid 


SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'T_SYN';

STATUS                                                                          
-------                                                                         
VALID
```

So first of all you need to check the existance of the object the synonym refers to.